# Opportunity in "Call To" field of "Phone call" activity in Dynamics 365 CE

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

A requirement from one of our client is that in Dynamics CRM, they want Opportunity entity to show up in the `Call To` field of a Phone Call entity. I have not been able to find anything online that will tell me how to do this or if this can be done.

In the `Call To` field of a Phone Call activity only Account, Contact and User entities are available, can we add Opportunity entity here?

Comment: Do you have follow-up questions? Also revisit all your questions, upvote/accept if the answers helped you, that will encourage volunteers to help you in future and the future readers can get benefit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with this two important pieces: `Regarding` & `ActivityParty`

---

**Regarding** is a special field type (for internal Activity only use, unavailable as datatype) which holds any entity as parent of that CRM Activity. We can only enable this (no disable option). I think this is the one you should be using.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I like this article [What developers need to know about the activity entity - by Ben Hosking](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/crm-2015-what-developers-need-to-know-about-the-activity-entity/).

---

**ActivityParty** is another special (very special) field type. ie **Party List** datatype.

> [image]

Read about it in [latest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/activityparty-entity), this is missing a crucial piece from [old documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328224(v=crm.8))

> An activity party represents another record (person or resource) that’s to be included in the activity. For example, it could be a contact, account, lead, **opportunity**, or queue.

It should allow to add any entity type, as this will be stored with its respective [PartyObjectTypeCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/activityparty#BKMK_PartyObjectTypeCode). You can enable/add entity to this bucket by adding `Email` type field in that entity or simply by checking this checkbox:

> [image]

You see this is disabled for Opportunity, and I don't remember about the past versions.

---

Opportunity is not a physical person anyway to be part of a call, but in xRM world anything is fine. You can try by adding an email type field in Opportunity to try your luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ArunVinoth. Will check it out.